# Assigning file lines to lists in python

Tags: python, list, file, lines, read-write

I have a "samples" file containing numbers in two lines(separated by a single space):
12 24 36
45 56 67

I would like to add these two lines in python to two lists which list1 then becomes ['12','24','36'] and the list2 becomes ['45','56','67']. I have written code that extracts these in desired format. My problem here is  I can not print these multiple lists with their **index**. For example how can I print only the first list ['12','24','36']. Below is the my code:

```
myfile=open('samples.txt','r')
for lines in myfile.readlines():
    results=lines.split()
    print(results)
```

Could you help me with this, please ?

Comment: you want to just stop after printing the first list?

Comment: Yes, I just want to get the first line. I do not know how to get "index" of multiple lists

Comment: Not a duplicate of that off topic closed question.

Comment: Sorry, I bothered you so much @cmd, but I mean we get a list but actually, it is not an actual list. I mean assuming I got results[0] and results [1] as outputs, but how can assign them to lists. My main problem is this. For example, I can not apply results[0].append method, because results[0] is not an actual python list therefore it does not append new element here. If possible, could you show how to do this, please ?

Comment: @coder results is a list of lists, if you want `list1` to be the first list, you would just say `list1 = results[0]`

Comment: Oh, yeah, I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('samples.txt','r') as myfile:
    results = [line.split() for line in myfile]
print(results[0])
```

or if you just want the first line

```
with open('samples.txt','r') as myfile:
    result = myfile.readline().split()
print(result)
```

to add them

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in result))
```

Comment: It does not work, unfortunately @cmd

Comment: @coder fixed typo, try now

Comment: Thank you @cmd. One thing I wish to ask. Is new one is a list ? Because I wanted to find sum of elements with print (sum(results[0])),  but it shows "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error